# How do you setup folder structure to seperate each screen on react native?

Tags: react-native

I have a problem to create a file structure to seperate each js UI code to be used

I wonder how to create js code of `welcome.js`, `login.js`, `splash,js` and call it when needed

> refer to [Navigation docs](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/navigation.html), it just declare the code of `Homescreen` and `ProfileScreen` without telling us how to build the best structure folder/file to create `Homescreen.js` and `ProfileScreen.js` and how to handle those UI code in `App.js`

Answer (score 1):

```
screens/
   index.js
   Welcome.js
   Login.js
   Splach.js
   package.json
```

where package.json has this code

```
{"name": "screens"}
```

import it like that :

```
import Welcome from 'screens/Welcome'
.
.
.
```

Answer (score 1):

That's a nice way:

```
/android
/ios
/src
  /components
  /containers
      App/
          index.js
          styles.js
      Welcome/
          index.js
          styles.js
      Login/
          index.js
          styles.js
      Splash/
          index.js
          styles.js
  /config
      ...
      containers.js
      router.js
  /images
package.json
index.ios.js
index.android.js
```

Answering to "refer to Navigation docs, it just declare the code of Homescreen and ProfileScreen without telling us how to build the best structure folder/file to create Homescreen.js and ProfileScreen.js and how to handle those UI code in App.js":

At `config/containers.js` you'll import all the `containers` modules. Then use the `router.js` to configure your StackNavigator like below.

```
import {
  StackNavigator
} from 'react-navigation';

import containers from './containers';

export const RootNav = StackNavigator({
  Splash: { screen: containers.Splash },
  Login: { screen: containers.Login },
  Home: { screen: containers.Welcome }
});
```

Now you can render the RootNav on the container `App/index.js`:

```
render(
    return(
        <RootNav navigation={this.props.navigation} />
    )
)
```

Answer (score 0):

you probably need to take a look at this 
[react native folder structure](https://hshno.de/ry43V0dpx)

this was similar with something I have ever done.